# Shortcut link of any directory is not visible when pasted in shared directory, to client computers

Tags: samba, shortcuts

I installed samba, and made a password protected shared directory. When I paste any file in shared directory, it is visible to other client computers. Now I want to share big file of 40 gb which is located on the same computer. I create shortcut link of that 40gb directory, and paste that shortcut link in shared directory. But, That shortcut link is not visible to clients. I don't want to waste hard-disk space by storing same big data twice.
How can I share a big file without storing it twice in in the same computer. Or any other method to do the same thing. I want it to be password protected and share with specific users.
i use 1TB  harddisk  that has win 8.1 and Ubuntu 20.04. It has 4 NTFS partition and 2 EXT4 partitions.

Comment: Probably it is a matter of configuring samba to allow following symbolic links.

Comment: It would be good if you briefly indicate the solution in an answer here, for the benefit of future users.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is working now, i added following things in addition to default settings.

[global]
"security = user"
"allow insecure wide links = yes"

[share]
"follow symlinks = yes"
"wide links = yes"
"force user = (username of root user)"

now i can use widelink successfully.
after more than 30 days of struggle, finally symlink and widelink works now.
please suggest if i can make some further amendments. many many thank you.